# JAX RS MediaType annotation values must be of the form 'name=value'

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am supposed to learn restful services using Java and JAX RS. I am trying to compile the following code, however I receive an error stating: `annotation values must be of the form 'name=value'`.

The code is in principle correct, it is equivalent with http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.xml.ws.Response;
import java.io.IOException;

@Path("/")
public class WebResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML)
    @XmlHeader("<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='=static/styles/atom2html.xsl' ?>")
    public Feed getFeed() {
        return FeedController.getInstance().getFeed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing several MediaType for the `@Produces` annotation so you need to put them in an array:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML})
```

Answer (score 0):

**OKAY:**  `@RequestMapping( "/employees" )`

**OKAY:**  `@RequestMapping( value = "/employees" )`

**OKAY:**  `@RequestMapping( value = "/employees" method = RequestMethod.GET )`

**NO!!:**  `@RequestMapping( "/employees" , method = RequestMethod.GET )`

Basically, you can be **implicit** with the endpoint path (value) but once you have both a value and method, you need to be **EXPLICIT**.

I realize this is for spring... But this is where I ended up after 15+ minutes of looking all around the place for the solution to my error. And my error was :

**annotation values must be of the form 'name=value'**